# How to set up Jenkins and sbt to run unit and integration tests as post-build action?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

How do you add a post-build action in Jenkins to kick off unit and integration tests using sbt 0.13? JUnit is the testing suite that I'm using, and there doesn't seem to be a way for the test results to be in a junitxml output.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/dependency-info.html) in your build.sbt to generate the xml report.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.maven.plugins" %% "maven-surefire-report-plugin" % "2.17"
```

Then your Post-build Action is to `Publish JUnit test result report`, which will be located here:

```
target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not using Maven, but sbt because I'm using the Play! framework which is based in Scala. 

Here's what I did: 

I installed the _Any Build Step Plugin_ and _Flexible Publish Plugin_. _Any Build Step Plugin_ allows me to treat any build step as a post-build action. I executed the shell script to run the unit and integration tests. Under **Action**, I chose `Publish JUnit test result report`, and put: `target/test-reports/*.xml`.